# Is there notation for an open OR closed interval?

Tags: notation

Is there a notation for indicating that an interval could be open or closed, (similar to the $\pm$ symbol meaning the operation could be $+$ or $-$)?

I am looking for an equivalent, less cumbersome way of writing something like "The domain of $f(x)$ is either $[a,b]$, or $[a,b)$, or $(a,b]$, or $[a,b]$."  Does such notation exist?

Comment: I have never seen notation for what you want, but when I needed something like this I would write something like "Let $I$ be an interval with endpoints $a$ and $b$."

Comment: I was just in the process of writing exactly this question. Is there a way to "bump" a question? About time someone invented such a notation.